# Serial rs232 communication Windows vs Linux

Tags: linux, windows, mono, serial-port

I am working with a device control software called ComScript, that my boss developed in c# for device control. (scientific applications) Recently it was ported to Linux using mono and the serial port control commands have stopped working(ComScript just hangs when asked to do any more than send simple strings). What are the main differences between the way Windows handles serial operations vs linux?

Comment: It's been awhile, but I remember some features of the SerialPort class are not supported on Mono. Not sure if that's what you are using, but I'm pretty sure Mono has only partial support. EDIT: not sure how date dthis post is but http://www.mono-project.com/HowToSystemIOPorts

Comment: As far as I remember, Windows does Serial as system calls, and *nix work them as special file accesses. If there is no "mapping" between the Windows system calls and the files, you will probably have to re-write serial port access to conform to *nix standards.